# Error in adding css in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/home.css">
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="d1">
    asfsdg
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to add styles to html elements in jsp page but when i add the style and run it on tomacat 9.0 nothing happens there and only plain text appears.
And when I moved to page source and click the links to css it shows me an error

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type Status Report

Message /TutorNextDoor/css/home.css

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M18
```

[image]

Comment: will you edit the post showing the folder structure? for what you are doing now your jsp is in a folder at the same level of css one. Is it correct?

Comment: I added the image showing structure

Comment: no it didnot worked

Comment: my css folder is in root directory

Comment: Move `css` (and `scripts`, too) folder to `WebContent` folder, then republish the webapp to Tomcat. The `WebContent` folder is root of your web application, the Tomcat cannot access the content "above" it. `TutorNextDoor` is your Eclipse project, but Eclipse project folder ≠ Web application root.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your css and scripts folder inside Webcontent and give the path in the html/jsp file in the following manner :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/scripts/jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/home.css">
    <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div id="d1">
            asfsdg
         </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```